# Zoom to a selected feature with Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have a function that allows me to change color to a selected feature in my layer's source. Within the same function I would like also to change the map view by zooming in to the selected feature extent.

Since I have different layers (with different sources) I have grouped first my layers and my sources

```
layers_group = [];
layers_group.push(layer_1, layer_2);

source_group = [];
source_group.push(source_1,source_2);
```

My function is as follows:

```
(function($) {
//when clicking the select
document.getElementById("show_feature").addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetSelectElement(region_select);
//first step it loads the vector layer and sets the style to transparent
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < layers_group.length; ++i){
        layers_group[i].setStyle(transparentStyle);
        layers_group[i].setVisible(true);
    };
//second step when the select changes (i.e. I make a choice)
    $("#show_feature").change(function() {
//it starts the function to change styles according to the selection made
        var selectedFeature = $("#show_feature").val();
        var index;
        for (index = 0; index < source_group.length; ++index){
            source_group[index].forEachFeature(function(feat){


    //if substring(selected text) exist within feature property('Region')
    //should return any value other than -1
                if (feat.get('Region').indexOf(selectedFeature)!=-1) {
                        //sets the style on the feature if it exists
                        feat.setStyle(selectStyle);
                        //should zoom to the selected feature polygon
                        var extent = feat.getGeometry().getExtent();
                        map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());

                } else {
                //and if it doesn't exist switch back to a transparent style - not visible
                feat.setStyle(transparentStyle);
                }
            });
        };

    });
});
})( jQuery );
```

Everything works well except for the zooming, as I get a "TypeError: map.getView is not a function" and no zooming is performed.

Could somebody help me in solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check `map` whether it has `getView` function.
and my suggestion about selecting feature and zooming is to use `ol.interaction.Select`.
select interaction with `select` event can do what you want.

```
// select interaction working on "click"
var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click
});

map.addInteraction(select);

select.on('select', function(e) {
  var extent = e.target.getFeatures().getArray()[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
  map.getView().fit(extent);
});
```

see codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwREXL)